# Tidydata - combining two dataset from different years - R to make a tidy data set

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have been reading Hadley Wickam's work on tidy data sets, and following his idea, I am trying to create a tidy dataset.

I currently have two datasets that contain the same variables for different years. I would like to merge the datasets, so that I have one dataframe, and the data for each year is on different lines.

e.g.

I have

```
Country .... Year .... GDP
Albania .... 2000 .... X1
Brazil  .... 2000 .... X3
China   .... 2000 .... X5

Country .... Year .... GDP
Albania .... 2010 .... X2
Brazil  .... 2010 .... X4
China   .... 2010 .... X6
```

And I would like to get

```
Country .... Year .... GDP
Albania .... 2000 .... X1
Albania .... 2010 .... X2
Brazil  .... 2000 .... X3
Brazil  .... 2010 .... X4
China   .... 2000 .... X5
China   .... 2010 .... X6
```

I run the following code

```
test1 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "country")
```

However, I end up with new variables called GDP.x and GDP.y.

Could someone help me solve this please?

Comment: I think rbind is my friend! I think I solved it

Comment: You should give it a try with `union_all` too.

Answer (score 4):

## Answer

You want to append/row bind the data.frames together, not join them. Try `bind_rows(df1, df2)` or `rbind(df1, df2)`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks bind_all and rbind seem to do the trick, as does union_all